# How to add a menu item keyboard shortcut where there is a duplicate menu item in the same sub menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, duplicate

I have seen the previous posts on this type of subject and nothing worked so far

In mail.app on osx lion 10.7 in the menu:

Format > Alignment > Writing Direction > Paragraph > Right to Left

and :

Format > Alignment > Writing Direction > Selection > Right to Left

As you can see there are 2 options to switch between writing directions to 'Right to Left' and back, the 'paragraph' and 'selection' in the same place and I have tried treating it like just another sub menu by typing this in the 'menu title' when adding a new keyboard shortcut :">Format>Alignment>Writing Direction>Paragraph>Right to Left" (without the quotes) and it still doesn't work.

Can anyone get this to work?

Thank You

Comment: Can you point us to the previous posts you've seen, please?

Answer (score 1):

The menu items seem to start with tabs:

[image]

I couldn't get the shortcuts to work even after adding tabs though.

---

You can enable shortcuts for changing the writing direction if a layout like Arabic is checked.

[image: 1]

Comment: I'd like to add that you can disable the RTL layout and the shortcuts are still there. I use a modified RTL layout (created by Ukelele) that when you select it, doesn't show "Enable keyboard shortcuts". I first selected Arabic, enabled shortcuts and then removed Arabic. Everything is perfect now.